# How to push TextInput in a FlatList in react native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I want to learn to use FlatList in react native,but I can't figure how to push elements in data (the FlatList array). Can someone help me ?

Here's my react native code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { FlatList, StyleSheet, Text, Button,View ,TextInput} from 'react-native';


export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {text: '',
    data:[]
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
      <TextInput
       style={{height: 40}}
          placeholder="Task"
          onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}/>
              <Button title="Add" onPress={this.addTask} />
      <FlatList

  renderItem={({item}) => <Text style={styles.item}>{item.key}</Text>}
/>
      </View>
    );
  }

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
   flex: 1,
   paddingTop: 22
  },
  item: {
    padding: 10,
    fontSize: 18,
    height: 44,
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add data prop in the Flatlist Component.

```
<FlatList
  data={[{key: 'a'}, {key: 'b'}]}
  renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.key}</Text>}
/>
```

the renderItem is basically looping over elements in the data array. It cannot do that if there is no data. If you are starting with empty data just use data={[]}